# C# DeploymentItem fails to copy file for MSTest unit test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest, deploymentitem

I'm having trouble getting an XSL file to be copied to the same directory as the test assembly when I use the `DeploymentItem` attribute on an MSTest unit test.  I followed the chosen answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883270/mstest-problems-with-deploymentitem-attribute) and the file I need copied has its "Copy to Output Directory" set to "Copy Always".  When I check my ProjectDir\bin directory (the Target directory), the file I want copied is indeed there, alongside the DLLs and PDBs.

I have a couple unit tests with the following setup:

```
private const string DLL = "Service.dll";
private const string XSL_PATH = "transform.xsl";

[TestInitialize]
public void InitializeTest()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(DLL)); // passes
}

[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem(DLL)]
[DeploymentItem(XSL_PATH)]
public void XmlToResultsTest()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(XSL_PATH)); // fails
}
```

The XSL test fails because when I check MSTest's TestResults\particularTestRun\Out directory, I see the DLLs and the PDBs, but my XSL file is not there.  What I want to know is *why* the XSL file does not get copied alongside the DLLs and PDBs even when I explicitly tell Visual Studio to copy it there via `DeploymentItem`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133879/c-using-static-variable-as-parameter-to-deploymentitem/2133926#2133926) to a related question of mine, I tried updating my MSTest .testrunconfig file so that my XSL file is included in the 'Deployment' section.  This lets my unit tests pass, but I'm still perturbed that I had to do this--shouldn't the combination of `DeploymentItem` and marking the file's properties in my project to copy to the output directory be sufficient?

Comment: I had this same problem Sarah - very confusing indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Allegedly VS2008 deployment items silently fail unless the output directory is a literal string. Hmmm ^_^

Comment: Where's your source for that?  If that's true, then that's just crazy.  I want my string constants, dang it!

Comment: Not something I've reproduced personally, but I had some deployment issues and googled around, found plenty of blogs saying they had problems with DeploymentItem, e.g:

http://sergeyshishkin.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!9F19E53BA9C1D63F!185.entry

Finally I opted for a global deployment folder in a .testrunconfig file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem even though I **was** using a literal string in the deployment item.  I even tried adding the file to the 'Deployment' section of the test settings which didn't work either.  It turned out that the problem was related to the testing platform.

I have a 64 bit machine and both the project I was testing and the unit test project's platform target were 'Any CPU'.

I found that the deployment item was only copied if I selected 'Run tests in a 64 bit process on 64 bit machine".

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar situation at work where the DeploymentItem attribute was not working as expected. We were also using 64 bit machines, with project platform set at "Any CPU". As a workaround, we included the file required by the unit test as a link from the unit test project and set its "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always".