# VS 2012 Generic Test Fails to Deploy Files

Tags: visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2012

I have a [Generic Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286732.aspx) defined in Visual Studio 2012.

If I hard code all the paths then the test runs perfectly. Obviously I need relative paths for this to work on a build server. **However, it fails to deploy my files because it is looking in the wrong place.**

Under *"Additional files to deploy with this generic test:"* my solution relative files appear like so (verbatim):

```
<Solution Directory>\SubDir\Tester.exe
```

When the test actually runs, the output shows the following error:

> Warning: Test Run deployment issue: Failed to get the file for
>   deployment item '\SubDir\Tester.exe' specified by the test
>   'generictest1': System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a
>   part of the path **'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE**\SubDir\Tester.exe'.

As you can see, It's using Visual Studio's working directory rather than the `'<Solution Directory>'` it claims.

Any ideas on how to fix this, or what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of related answered questions about this issue:
[Problems with DeploymentItem attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883270/problems-with-deploymentitem-attribute)
[C# DeploymentItem fails to copy file for MSTest unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134099/c-sharp-deploymentitem-fails-to-copy-file-for-mstest-unit-test)

However, in VS 2012 MS did changes to MSTest (unfortunately I cannot find URLs to the couple of blog posts that they did about these changes - they were mentioned a bit in-between the other new stuff they did) so now when you have an assembly as a deployment item - either from a test class, test method or a TestSettings file, it might still be left out!

The reason seems to be that mstest looks for class instantiation from referenced assemblies. If there is none, the assembly will not get copied. We had this problem with tests that were using a framework which in turn used NewtonSoft.JSON. We had to create a dummy test class and method that instantiated any class from the NewtonSoft.JSON lib so that its DLL would be copied.

Give it a go and fingers crossed that it works.